# cmake doesn't display display message

Tags: c, cmake

```
Fedora 15
cmake version 2.8.4
```

I am using the following CMakeLists.txt. However the status message doesn't display when I run `cmake .`

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.6)

PROJECT(proj2 C)

IF(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
    MESSAGE(STATUS "==== GCC detected - Adding compiler flags")
    SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-pthread -ggdb -Wextra -Wall")
ENDIF(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(crypto_app main.c)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(crypto_app crypt)
```

All I get is the following:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/lib64/ccache/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/lib64/ccache/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/projects/proj1/
```

Many thanks for any suggestions about this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're telling cmake that it's a C project, and then checking for a CXX (i.e. C++) compiler. `CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX` will never be true in this case. That's why.

Comment: Thanks Chris, should have used this CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC